# How to set class "help(class)" method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an example class:

```
class Foo_class:
    """ Foo_class """
    def __init__(self,x=0):
        self.x=x
```

But I can't to find information how to set help method to `Foo_class`. For `help()` func:

```
f=Foo_class()
print(type(f),type(f).__name__,end='\n'*2)
help(type(f).__name__)
```

its outs:

[image]

I tried to find *"class help method"* and *"Python documentation for class"*, but no result.

Its may to use simple `help(Foo_class)`, but its only print the `Foo_class` code list.

If try to use for example for **list**: `help(list)` or `help(type(list).__name__)` its **return relevant information** : *`Help on class type ...`*

IS it possible for a regular class, or only for a package?

Comment: For your own classes, you should pass the class itself to `help`, not the `__name__`.

Comment: Yes, this type is return class code. But if class has help inf, its return and as `help(type(class).__name__)` and as `help(class)`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you're trying to say at all. You should write `help(type(f))` (or `help(Foo_class)`), then you will see the documentation for the class. You do not need to call `print`. The `help` function already prints, it does not return a string. It will also work with the object, just `help(f)`.

Comment: Just use `help(type(f)` or `help(Foo_class)`. Both will print the doc string in the class definition (if any) — the one in yours consists of just the class name.

Comment: It’s more correct help without print, but it relevant worked print(help) and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just print out not the type of class object. Do `print(help(Foo_class))` and in the output you can see your docsting